# Setting up referral system for e-commerce using Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am attempting to generate a unique code for each user that signs up on my Parse Platform. Think of this as a referral code. After studying codes generated by apps like Uber, Ola, Flipkart, I have decided to do it this way -

1)First name of the user is taken and concatenated with the first letter of his Last name.

2)This is then used as a base referral code appended with a number starting at 000. If a code like this exists the number is incremented. Thinking of using a 3 digit hexadecimal number to allow for flexibility.

3)Once a unique code has been generated, it is stored in my parse database.

4) The user class has a column storing its respective referral code and there is also another referral code class that has inputs as each unique referral code generated. This is currently the structure I'm thinking of.

What I have done so far -

```
Parse.Cloud.define("generateReferralCode", function(request, response){
var objectId=request.params.data;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
query.equalTo("objectId", objectId);
query.first({
  success: function(user) {
    response.success(" Received user info ");
    var name=user.getUsermame;
    var lowerCaseName= name.toLowerCase();
    var words = lowerCaseName.split(" ");
    var baseCode= words[0] + words[1].charAt(0);           

  },error: function() {
      response.error("Something went horribly wrong!");
    }
});
})
```

What I have to do is append a 3 digit hexa number such that its unique and one more than the last (largest) number there is already there.

Comment: Some comments: 1) There may be a typo on setting the "baseCode" variable - words[1].chatAt(0) should probably be charAt(0). 2) Note that this approach is not really thread-safe, as two people may get the same number, if they have the same name and first letter of last name, and both request the number before the system persists either of them. So some optimistic tests should be in order (i.e. assume it'll work, but handle failures).

Comment: yes, didnt notice. Any suggestions on setting up a code generator ?

Comment: So what kind of tests? This same issue is there when using Parse's beforeSave cloud code. If two people trigger the code at the same time it can lead to the same issues and I cant find any solution to that either.

Comment: Is there a central place, such as a  database, enforcing this uniqueness? If so, the request that's effectively late will get to the error state, while the first one will go smoothly. So that's your check. If there's no such place, you'll need to write one. Or switch to UUID-based approach or the like.

Comment: I didn't understand.  Sorry but could you elaborate?

Comment: UUID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) takes all kinds of probably unique data into account, so it's very very unlikely for two UUIDs to be the same. But you end up with an ugly string like ecc01252-5c5a-11e5-a93c-20c9d048ce61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("generateReferralCode", function(request, response){
var objectId=request.params.data;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
query.equalTo("objectId", objectId);
query.first({
  success: function(user) {
    var name=user.get("ProfileName");
    var lowerCaseName= name.toLowerCase();
    var words = lowerCaseName.split(" ");
    var baseCode= words[0] + words[1].charAt(0)+ words[1].charAt(1)+ words[1].charAt(2);
   // Can take only words[1].chatAt(0) and ignore the others.
  var referral= Parse.Object.extend("ReferralCode");
   var queryR = new Parse.Query(referral);
   queryR.startsWith("referralCodeColumn", baseCode);
   queryR.find({
  success: function(results) {
    var number= results.length;
    var hexaString = (number).toString(16);
    var referralCode = baseCode+hexaString;
    response.success(referralCode);

  },
  error: function(error) {
    response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }});

  },error: function() {
      response.error("Something went horribly wrong!");
    }
});
});
```

Ok so the system I am using is as follows

- User's profile is taken and split into two words
- A 'base code' is generated by taking the first name and the first letter of the second name
- Existing codes that have the same starting are counted from a query. The number is incremented and appended to the 'base code' and finally stored in parse database

The code on the android side is

```
            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        HashMap atMap = new HashMap<>();
                        String objectId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
                        atMap.put("data", objectId);
                        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("generateReferralCode", atMap, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(String value, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Log.d("Referral code is", value);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: failed to sign up " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

If two users with the same Name register together, then they may both be given the same referral code which defeats the purpose. To counter this, I will be using an afterSave trigger which I will incorporate at a later stage. Hence to make this situation even more unlikely I am taking the first name and the first 3 letters of the last name, reducing the chances of this problem from occurring which IS NOT THE IDEAL WAY!

**Same Code**
Varun Agarwal --> [varun, agarwal] --> varunaga --> varunaga + 'number'

The first referral code will be varunaga0 , then varunaga1 till varunagaf and then it becomes varunaga10.